# trying to fade one type into another on hover - CSS3 or Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

My dilemma is I know how to fade one image into another on hover using the jquery animate method:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("img.a").hover(function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, "slow");
    },function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, "slow");
    });
});
```

And I also know how to use CSS3 Transitions to change the hover color on text:

```
a.squirrel{
color:black;  
padding:5px; 
-webkit-border-radius: 5px; 

-webkit-transition-property:color, background; 
-webkit-transition-duration: 1s, 1s; 
-webkit-transition-timing-function: linear, ease-in;
} 
a.squirrel:hover{color:red;}
```

What I don't know how do, but want to do, is to take a link with one kind of font like Georgia (trying to keep it simple for demonstration purposes) and when you hover over it, fade it into a totally different kind of type such as Tahoma.

I've using both of these methods, but neither seems to give me the desired effect.

I know I can use the images of the type I want to use, but I'm trying not to use images, so vanilla Javascript or some other jQuery method is what I'm looking for.

Is this possible to do??

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about actually creating a smooth transform between font-style's this really isn't possible.  But, if you just want to create a fade effect on hover to transition between two font styles, something like this should work:

http://jsfiddle.net/7NATE/8/

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <span class="font1">Hello World!</span>
    <span class="font2">Hello World!</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.font1{
    font-family: Tahoma;
}

.font2{
    font-family: Georgia;
    display: none;
}
```

JS

```
var $f1 = $(".font1"), $f2 = $(".font2"), $c = $('#container');

$c.hover(function(){    
    if(!$f1.is(':animated') && !$f2.is(':animated')){
        $f1.fadeOut(function(){
             $f2.fadeIn();
        });
    }
},
function(){
    if(!$f1.is(':animated') && !$f2.is(':animated')){
        $f2.fadeOut(function(){
            $f1.fadeIn();
        });
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using .fadeOut, .load a new image to the element and then .fadeIn? The fadein/out function is a lot more convenient than using opacity.. you can even change the speed and "slope" of the transition..

Answer (score 0):

In either way, css or js, I don't we can change font-family in slow motion.

For color, background, width, height, or etc, We can calculate the state in each frame when it is animated.

But for font-family, I don't think it's possible to calculate frame state during the period of animation, unless font-family is an image, but it is not.